# Include and ThenInclude with multiple levels of collections

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I am trying to query an entity with multiple levels of collections, and multiple collections at a single level.  I'm using `Include()` and `ThenInclude()`, but not having much success.  The examples I find don't have multiple collections on the same level and I haven't had any luck applying the technique to my use case.

This is a simplified illustration of my entities.  Those with the [] are collections:

```
Home
   Areas[]
       Area
           Name
           Categories[]
               Name
               Recommendations[]
               Subcategories[]
                   Name
                   Recommendations[]
       Area
           Name
           Categories[]
               Name
               Recommendations[]
               Subcategories[]
                   Name
                   Recommendations[]
```

I've gotten this far:

```
result = Home
    .Include(x => x.Areas)
    .ThenInclude(a => a.Categories)
    .ThenInclude(c => c.Subcategories)
    .ThenInclude(s => s.Recommendations)
```

However, this misses the `Categories[].Recommendations[]` collection.  It's because there are two collections at the same level (`Recommendations[]` and `Subcategories[]`).

Any suggestions for a way to structure this query so I can get the desired result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call `Include` for each level:

```
result = Home
    .Include(x => x.Areas)
        .ThenInclude(a => a.Categories)
        .ThenInclude(c => c.Subcategories)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.Recommendations)
    .Include(x => x.Areas)
        .ThenInclude(a => a.Recommendations)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your query as follows:

```
result = Home
    .Include(x => x.Areas)
        .ThenInclude(a => a.Categories)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.Recommendations)
   .Include(x => x.Areas)
       .ThenInclude(c => c.Subcategories)
```